# Set WP User Role conditionally using Auth.0 rule at SSO

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, auth0

Currently building a WordPress intranet site, that authenticates users using Auth.0 SSO, against the company's Azure AD. The SSO functions properly, but I'm trying to get more granular with access control using Auth.0's "rules". The ideal result is a rule that specifies (updates) the user's WP Profile with a user role based on their job title from AD. The code below has been modified from one of Auth.0's rule templates, and runs clean. However, it doesn't work - I'm not sure what particular arguments/functions I need to actually update the role in WordPress. I'll be up-front and admit that I'm far from proficient in JS. Any thoughts?

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (user.job_title === 'IT/Marketing Coordinator') {
    user.vip = true;
  }
  callback(null, user, context);
  }
```

In the example above, it successfully sets "user.vip" to "true" (which really doesn't prove much except that the rule executes without error.

Answer (score 1):

this rule, as you said, is fine and will add this attribute.

The issue is that you will need to do something from the wordpress side to make it work (that the user has a vip flag doesn't mean anything to WordPress).

What you can do is hook to the auth0_user_login action that is fired each time a user logs in and based on the user profile set/change the user role.

This is how you hook to the action:

```
add_action( 'auth0_user_login', 'auth0UserLoginAction', 0,5 ); 

function auth0UserLoginAction($user_id, $user_profile, $is_new, $id_token, $access_token) { 
... 
}
```

I think you will find this WP doc useful to update the user role: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Comment: Where do you actually add the add_action code?  Somewhere within the Auth0 plugin codebase?  Or is it elsewhere?  New to WP Plugin development, but I need to implement similar functionality as the OP.